# Is there a way to set time-limit for pre-signed url in s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I am just exploring **pre-signed URLs** in **s3** and wanted to know is it possible to `generate pre-signed URL from console` instead of using SDK?

Also, is there a way to `set a time-limit for the expiration of pre-signed URL from console, based on few other post on stack the default time limit is 7 days, how to override this value?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as this date, no. There is no option in the web console to generate a sign URL.

And for your second question; yes, you can override the default URL expiration using the SDK.

AWS CLI example:

```
aws s3 presign s3://<bucket-name>/<file-name> --expires-in <seconds>
```

[AWS CLI documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html)

Comment: understood the first part of your answer,for the default pre-signed URL generated which we can access in console is there a way to override `its URL expiration` from console not `sdk`?

Comment: nope, any `presign` operation (including overriding URL expiration) is simply not available through console. (Hopefully Amazon will change this in the future).